# incorrect geolocation through linux-routed OpenVPN

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn

I am located in Europe. I have set up a linux virtual machine which establishes an OpenVPN tunnel (StrongVPN) to a server in the USA, and acts as a router through appropriate iptables. Any client pointing to the linux VM as a gateway uses the VPN to connect to the internet. Accordingly, geolocation shows the clients as being in the USA.

However, when I point the gateway of a video streamer (Minix or AppleTv) to the VM gateway, TV services (such as Amazon Prime) seem to still believe that the streamer is located in Europe.

HTTP-based geolocation services from the Minix streamer show that it is using the correct VPN tunnel. Moreover, if I start the StrongVPN client directly from the streamer (only possible on the Minix, not on AppleTv), everything goes through the tunnel and Amazon Prime is available. Any suggestions on what might be happening?

Comment: Two shots in the dark: 1) they check the timezone of the client 2) there is a "side channel" and some requests do not go through the VPN (do you route everything throug the VPN?)

Comment: Do you route IPv6 through the VPN?

Comment: I have not routed IPv6 explicitly through the VPN. Iptables -S yields: 
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.10.0.0/16 -i eth0 -o tun0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
What do I need to do to include IPv6?